# Solving $\left| {2z + 3i} \right| = \left| {{z^2}} \right|$

Tags: complex-numbers

[image]

This is a multiple choice question with one or more correct, my approach is as follow

$\left| {2z + 3i} \right| = \left| {{z^2}} \right| \Rightarrow \left| {2\left( {a + ib} \right) + 3i} \right| = \left| {{a^2} - {b^2} + i2ab} \right|$

$ \Rightarrow \left| {2a + i\left( {2b + 3} \right)} \right| = \left| {{a^2} - {b^2} + i2ab} \right| \Rightarrow {\left| {2a + i\left( {2b + 3} \right)} \right|^2} = {\left| {{a^2} - {b^2} + i2ab} \right|^2}$

$ \Rightarrow 4{a^2} + {\left( {2b + 3} \right)^2} = {\left( {{a^2} - {b^2}} \right)^2} + 4{a^2}{b^2} = {\left( {{a^2} + {b^2}} \right)^2} \Rightarrow 4{a^2} + {\left( {2b + 3} \right)^2} = {\left( {{a^2} + {b^2}} \right)^2}$

Not able to procced further

Answer (score 1):

$|z|^2 = |2z+3i| \le 2|z|+3 \Rightarrow |z| \le 3$ with equality when $z=3i$

Also $|z|^2 = |2z-(-3i)| \ge 3-2|z| \Rightarrow |z| \ge 1$ with equality when $z=-i$

Answer (score 0):

By what it looks like, the question most likely does not want you to proceed to solve $a$ or $b$. Since, this is multiple choice you can try proving each option true/false by "catering" your method towards it;

For example, Option A states $3 \ge \|z\| > u$. You found $a^2 + b^2 = \sqrt{4a^2 + (2b + 3)^2}$.

Let $\{f(a,b): a^2 + b^2 = k\}$ and $\{g(a,b): a^2 + (b + \frac{3}{2})^2 = \frac{k^2}{4}\}$, $k \in \mathbb{R^+}$. $f(a, b)$ has the centre, $C_1 = (0, 0)$ and $g(a,b)$ has the centre, $C_2 = (0, -\frac{3}{2})$, with respect to $a,b$ axes. **Since, $\|z\| = \sqrt{k}$, we need to disprove that $k > 9$ or prove that $k < 9$ for all $a, b$. Let's claim that $k < 9$.**

Both $f(a, b)$ and $g(a, b)$ are elliptic functions on the cartesian plane. By the solving $k = \frac{k^2}{4}, k ≠ 0$, we observe that both elliptic function have same radii at $k = 4$. The function $\frac{k^2}{4}$ has a greater gradient ($>\frac{d}{dk}$) after $k = 4$, than $k$. Hence, $g(a, b)$ will "grow" in size faster than $f(a, b)$ as $k$ approaches $\infty$.

What this indicates, is that there is a certain $k$ value (Let this be denoted by $x$), for which values $>x$, $f(a, b) = \sqrt{g(a, b)}$ stop having solutions.

If our claim is true, there are $2$ solutions to $f(a, b) = \sqrt{g(a, b)}$, for $k < 9$, $1$ solution for $k = 9$ and $0$ solutions for $k > 9$.

Using the elliptic definition on cartesian plane ($a$ = horizontal axis, $b$ = vertical axis (interchangeable, but once defined, keep consistent)), the $2$ solutions always exist for $\{b: b > -\sqrt{k}, b < \frac{k}{2} - \frac{3}{2} \}$. Hence,

$\frac{k - 3}{2} > -\sqrt{k}, k > 0$

$\frac{(k - 3)^2}{4} < k$

$k^2 - 10k + 9 < 0$

$(k - 9)(k - 1) < 0$

We find that $9 \ge k \ge 1$, for  $1$ or $2$ solutions to $a^2 + b^2 = \sqrt{4a^2 + (2b + 3)^2}$. The claim is true.

Hence, $1 \le \|z\| \le 3$. Therefore, **Option A is correct**.

For $1 \le \|z\| \le 3$, if $\|z\| \in N$, then, $\|z\| = 1, 2, 3$. Hence, **Option B is correct**.

If $\|z\| = 3$, $\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = 9 \to \alpha^2 = 9 - \beta^2$

Then $81 = 36 - 4\beta^2 + 4\beta^2 + 12\beta + 9 \to b = 3$. Since $\beta = \|z\|_{max}$, $\alpha = 0$ and $\alpha^3 + \beta^3 = 0^3 + 3^3 = 27$. Hence, **Option C is correct**.

Option D is left as an exercise.